# Provider for javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory cannot be found

Tags: java, xml

I am not able to get past this problem. Browsed through many forums. Pls help:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is
>   javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for
>   javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory cannot be found.

I have included all the jar files in xerces bin. 
Following is my WEB-INF/lib structure:

[image: Lib]

Comment: [Possibly Duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526419/unexpected-exception-parsing-xml-document-from-servletcontext-resource-web-inf)

Comment: I am not sure but looks like the implementation of DocumentFactoryBuilder is not found even after adding the jar files

Comment: Then try with different jars from [Here](http://www.findjar.com/class/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html) [Usage](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.java) [More Info](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/2064/a-simple-way-to-read-an-xml-file-in-java/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could resolve the above problem entirely, by setting the order in which classloader should load the xerces jar files (WAR->EAR->Server). The following link is taken from Xerces site at Apache. It helps to resolve the above issue for Websphere Portal/WAS:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0310_searle/searle.html

Answer (score 17):

We have this problem also when upgrade spring and jpa/hibernate from 3 to 4. For us it is because hibernate-entitymanager 4.3.11 has a dependency on jdom which has a dependency on xml-apis which will conflict with the JRE’s rt.jar’s javax.xml stuff. We exclude it so that our spring xml config could be correctly parsed.
To solve the problem, we can just exclude the xml-apis from the dependency tree.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Battlecruiser Operational

Comment:   Fantastic!

Answer (score 4):

I also had this problem working with WebSphere Portal 8. I was recently using xalan 2.7.0 for accessing and parsing XML.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

After removing the xml-apis (like Leon Li did) it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution (by browsing through some forums):

1. Go to the location where your JRE is present.
   For example, since I am using Websphere Portal JRE, I went to this location:C:\Program Files\IBM5\WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre\lib
2. Open the jaxb.properties file and modify the property **javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory** to suite your xml parser. In my case it is:
   javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl

I have been promoted to the next problem :). I am getting a ClassCastException now. Following is the log:

Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl

All help is welcome. Thank you

Comment: This might help. https://community.jboss.org/thread/152151  Try removing the xml-apis.jar from your build.